# wordpress couldn't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

I am trying to set up Wordpress on my mac. I have done all the setup. when i hit my website, it asks for hostname,username, password. After filling up the details. I get the below message.

On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_. Could that be the problem?

I have checked the user privileges to the DB. Everything seems fine. Not sure why is it not working still. Please note DB connection is established and using mamp.

Comment: Cn u attach the Screenshot pls

Comment: have you added username password and host in config.php?

Comment: screengrab please

Comment: I am not sure what was the issue. I removed the password from the phpadmin for the user "root" and removed pwd from config file. It then worked ... Still not sure what was the issue if i use the pwd.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using mac , there will be a default thing with some systems that was your database name start with your user-name if you are developing in local environment then it will be that username_dbname , if you are developing it under live server i.e any host based platform then you will get that as hostuserid_dbname , so make sure that you use host-name and db name with user-name (local) or hostuserid(live) and  user-name of db with user-name (local) or hostuserid(live) in cofig.php file located in your wordpress file or if you installing wordpress for first time then it will ask you graphically so that you an use the details and set it up .

Comment: I am not sure what was the issue. I removed the password from the phpadmin for the user "root" and removed pwd from config file. It then worked ... Still not sure what was the issue if i use the pwd.